# My recycler view is skipping my onResponse call

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

The data I get from the api is not getting added into my recycler view. The api is working as i can display data via a text view and so is the recycler view as i can add stuff out with line 39 The issue has to be with line 39 in main. Thanks

```
fun getApiData(): ArrayList<String>{
var list = ArrayList<String>()

//This one gets added
list.add("THIS STUFF")

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
val service = retrofit.create(NewsApi::class.java)
val call = service.getNews()
call.enqueue(object : Callback<NewsResponse> {

    //I Thinks this part is the problem  for some for some reason recyclerView() just skips it
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<NewsResponse>, response: Response<NewsResponse>, ) {


        if (response.code() == 200) {
            val newsResponse = response.body()!!

            list.add("This WAS NOT ADDED")
            list.add(newsResponse.results[2].title)
            list.add(newsResponse.results[3].title)

            val stringBuilder = "Section is : " + newsResponse.section +
                    "\n" + list[1] +
                    "\n" + newsResponse.results[1].title +
                    "\n" + newsResponse.results[2].title +
                    "\n" + newsResponse.results[3].title +
                    "\n" + newsResponse.results[4].title + "bjhkh ddgg"
            textView.text = stringBuilder
        }
    }
    override fun onFailure(call: Call<NewsResponse>, t: Throwable) {
    }
})
return list
```

}

```
fun recyclerView(){
    // Adapter class is initialized and list is passed in the param.
    val itemAdapter = ItemAdapter(this, getApiData())

    recycler_view_items.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    // adapter instance is set to the recyclerview to inflate the items.
    recycler_view_items.adapter = itemAdapter
}
```

Comment: Can you share the json for response?

Answer (score 0):

API call takes time to load the list, so it will not set immediately data to the list. you are returning the list just after calling API. you should be doing it in API response.

Here is the code you can use.

```
fun fetchList() {

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        val service = retrofit.create(NewsApi::class.java)
        val call = service.getNews()
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<NewsResponse> {

            //I Thinks this part is the problem  for some for some reason recyclerView() just skips it
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<NewsResponse>, response: Response<NewsResponse>, ) {


                if (response.code() == 200) {
                   
                    val newsResponse = response.body()!!
                    val list = ArrayList<String>()
                    list.add(newsResponse.results[2].title)
                    list.add(newsResponse.results[3].title)
                    
                    // Adapter class is initialized and list is passed in the param.
                    val itemAdapter = ItemAdapter(this, list)

                    recycler_view_items.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

                    // adapter instance is set to the recyclerview to inflate the items.
                    recycler_view_items.adapter = itemAdapter
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<NewsResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            }
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you never update the dataset of **adapter**, for this you can create a method in this like these

```
    fun addItems(clear: Boolean,list: List<String>){
    if(clear){
        this.items.clear()//this is the list that fill your adapter, if you want to clear all data put true
    }
    this.items.addAll(list)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

When your API call is ended you can call this method Here

```
call.enqueue(object : Callback<NewsResponse> {

//I Thinks this part is the problem  for some for some reason recyclerView() just skips it
override fun onResponse(call: Call<NewsResponse>, response: Response<NewsResponse>, ) {


    if (response.code() == 200) {
        val newsResponse = response.body()!!

        list.add("This WAS NOT ADDED")
        list.add(newsResponse.results[2].title)
        list.add(newsResponse.results[3].title)

        val stringBuilder = "Section is : " + newsResponse.section +
                "\n" + list[1] +
                "\n" + newsResponse.results[1].title +
                "\n" + newsResponse.results[2].title +
                "\n" + newsResponse.results[3].title +
                "\n" + newsResponse.results[4].title + "bjhkh ddgg"
        textView.text = stringBuilder
        itemAdapter.addItems(true, list);//if you want to clear all data
    }
}
override fun onFailure(call: Call<NewsResponse>, t: Throwable) {
}
```

})

Comment: he is returning an empty list right after API call, notifyDataSetChanged() data will not work here I guess.

Comment: okay you have a bit reason, first he need to put the array of data on the adapter and after notify

Comment: Yes, exactly. otherwise, an empty array will be notified